# How to determine a value based on dynamic ranges in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a clever way to determine, say an array index, that falls within a given range?  The application is similar to a playlist for a single video file with a set of from/to times that denote a "chapter".
i.e. Chapters:

```
00:01 - 00:30 : Call To Order
00:31 - 00:45 : Pledge of Allegence
00:46 - 02:25 : Opening Remarks
02:26 - 32:07 : Old Business
etc., etc., etc.
```

I have a list of these items on the page, and as the player reports where in the video it is currently playing by returning the current timestamp, I need to use jQuery to highlight the LI of the "chapter" in which the currently video timestamp falls.  So if the video is currently at 1:15, that's "Opening Remarks", and the 3rd list item would be highlighted.

I've tried a number of approaches, but ultimately use PHP to write a huge series of IF/ELSEs because a playlist could have anywhere from 5 to 100 different Chapters in it and can be modified by the user at any time.

Ideally, I'd like an array using the Start time as the Key and chapter as the value, and a function that returns the first index that is >= the current timestamp.  Is there any clever approach to accomplishing this?  My way "works", but good God, its inefficient, running through 100 if/elses 10 times per second.

P.S. I should mention that all values are actually in seconds, with the question using H:M:S for clarity.  Ultimately, I'm trying to understand how to select an array index if it falls within a given range.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var chapters = {
    1: "callToOrder",
    31: "pledgeOfAllegiance",
    46: "openingRemarks",
    146: "oldBusiness", 
}

function currentChapter(seconds) {
    var start, found = Infinity;
    for (start in chapters) {
        if (start <= seconds && start < found) {
            found = start;
        }
    }
    return (found === Infinity) ? null : chapters[found];
}
```

It will run in linear time in the number of chapters. In practice, this should be acceptable. If it isn't, then you could replace `chapters` with an array of objects and perform a binary search.

Comment: This looks great, though it's the Index, not the Value I need, so returning "found" instead of chapters[found] would accomplish that, and returning chapters.length-1 would return the last index if the full length of the video had not been specified in the chapter list.